# How to deal with product coefficients in a nonlinear model?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, identifiability

I am considering a nonlinear regression model as the following:

`y=(ax)*(bz)+u,`

where the sample are IID, u is random error term such that E(u|x,z)=0, and a and b are coefficients for x and z, respectively. I would like to apply the nonlinear least square (NLS) estimator to estimate a and b (i.e., `nls(y~ax*bz, start=list(a=1.5,b=0.5)`. However, there is parameter identification issue here. Namely, I cannot obtain the coefficients estimates of a and b *individually*, but *jointly*. For instance, if the true value of a*b=-1, then I may obtain a=-1, b=1, or a=1, b=-1.

**Question**: Is it feasible to obtain the estimates of a and b *individually*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not feasible for mathematical reasons, as there is an infinite number of combinations of a and b.

$y=(ax)*(bz)+u$

can be written as

$y=(a\cdot x)\cdot(b\cdot z)+u$

which again can be written as

$y=(a\cdot b)\cdot(x\cdot z)+u$

So you can estimate the optimal value for $(a\cdot b)$ and then, for every $a$ you choose there is an $b = (a\cdot b)\div a$

That gives an infinite number of possible solutions and you gave your computer no hint, which one to choose. Compute the joint coefficient, call it $(a\cdot b)$ and if you have other reasons (i. e. reasons not stated here) to prefer any of these pairs of $a$ and $b$ you are free to choose.

Btw you do not need `nls` for this joint coefficient, you can use `lm` as in

```
x <- runif(20, 0, 100)
z <- rnorm(20)
y <- jitter(5*x*z)

# either optimizer
nls(y ~ ab*x*z, start = list(ab=1)) 
# or linear regression
summary(lm(y ~ x:z - 1))
```

Among the advantages of `lm` are, that you do not need start values and get a standard error and R² for free.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. That is the same to my conjecture that, without further restriction on the parameters, the solution is infinite. I wondered if there can be some tricks in R that allows for such model to be implemented, such as minimizing nonlinear objeccive function with linear constraint.

Comment: BTW, the original question is about to consistently estimate $y=g_1(x_1)g_2(x_2)+u$ where both $g_1(.)$  and $g_2(.)$ are unknown and smooth function. But still the question is the same: how can one to estimate the two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ using spline or Chebeshev polynomials through NLS?

Comment: Depending on the circumstances it might be reasonable to add sensible restrictions. It might be sensible to choose $a$ and $b$ in a manner that both are af the same size $a = b$. A very elegant way is Bayesian regression with even weak prior information an $a$ and $b$ to restrict them to sensible parameters. If there just are no other restrictions, use just any pair of $a$ and $b$ the optimizing algorithm throws out. Whilst `nls` will throw an error, `optim` doesn't really care: Try `optim(c(1, 1), function(arg) sqrt(sum(y-arg[1]*x*arg[2]*z)^2))` Beware: Start values matter a lot!

Comment: @ Bernhard Thank you again. Right, the problem I am facing is to use _any pair of a and b the optimizing algorithm throws out_. I am using `bobyqa()`, but essentially it does the same thing as `optim()`. The problem is that for each time I perform such optimization using a pair of (a,b) as my starting values, the magnitude (or the sign) of a or b estimates changes, although a*b remains the same. Again, this is the identification problem you mentioned above. So I am guessing without further restriction imposed on (a,b), I cannot consistently estimate them _individually_, am I right?

Comment: Nope. Without further restrictions there are no true values, which is why you cannot consistently estimate them.

Comment: That is right. But thank you for your explanation throughout !